# How to identify a new topic created in a kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, yahoo-kafka-manager

I want to identify any new topic created in Kafka cluster. Using zookeeper we can get a list of topics created. But I want to continuously get alerts for new topics created. Also is there a way to solve this using yahoo Kafka manager or LinkedIn burrow?